# Why are the output "0" when converting to binary variable 0 or 1

Tags: r

There are 48 observations with USA origin and 45 with Non-USA origin, but all the results shown "0" after the writing code below. What's problem here?

```
library(MASS)

for (i in 1: length(Cars93$Origin)) {
    if(Cars93$Origin == " USA") {
        Cars93$origin_binary <- 1
    }
    else {
        Cars93$origin_binary <- 0
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a whitespace in front of the USA, might be the problem.

Comment: `Cars93$origin_binary <- as.integer(Cars93$Origin == "USA")` should be enough. No need for `for` loop. Moreover, in your `for` loop you need to use `i`, `Cars93$origin_binary[i]`. All the values turn to 0 because the last value is `"non-USA"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your `for` loop as pointed out by @RonakShah and @Daniel. Moreover, you are assigning a value to a column that is most likely not defined before starting your `for` loop.

If you really want to stick the `for` loop, you can do:

```r
Cars93$origin_binary <- 0
for(i in 1:length(Cars93$Origin))
{
    if(Cars93$Origin[i] == "USA"){Cars93$origin_binary[i] <- 1}
    else {Cars93$origin_binary[i] <- 0}
}
```

Howver, the alternative using `ifelse` could be simpler:

```r
Cars93$origin_binary = ifelse(Cars93$Origin == "USA",1,0)
```

Comment: Got it, Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Of course good answer from dc37, however don't forget about base R, it's easy and simple. Actually with base R and `dplyr` you won't need loops anymore regarding manipulating data.

```
Cars93$origin_binary[Cars93$Origin == "USA"] = 1
Cars93$origin_binary[is.na(Cars93$origin_binary)] = 0
```

or

```
Cars93$origin_binary[Cars93$Origin != "USA"] = 0
```

Comment: And of course `Cars93$origin_binary <- as.integer(Cars93$Origin == "USA")` by @RonakShah and @PoGibas. I think, that's simplest way to do this.